# MS Access:Update the property of items in a form after I change the property of the same item in table

Tags: ms-access

I create a table and a form out of the table.  However, after I change the property of the item in a table, (say, make it from direct text input to a yes/no list), the same item in form does not update automatically for that. Is there a way to make MS Access to do this job?

Comment: You can code this, but why? How often does this happen? If it happens delete the control from the form and assing it again, then it uses the proper control type.

Comment: I set up a form with many controls.  But later I want to change the controls from simple text to a list.  Delete them would be one option, but I do not get why the form in Access is not synchronized with table.  The two (table and form) should have a closer relationship.  Anyway,  thanks!